# Finding and Closing All Child Windows of a WPF Window

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, winforms

Ok so I have a WPF application that has a WinForms project in it.  My main project is the WPF one.  My question is how do I find all of the widows that are children of my Main Window that is WPF?? These Windows can be either WinForm or WPF so i need a way to determine of which type the child is to successfully close said form and all of its potential children.

Thank you in advance for the assistance

Comment: WPF "with WinForms project in it" is not very clear. Better clarify (with some code).

Comment: Im sorry.  Its a WPF Solution with a WPF Project as the Start Up and a WinForms Project with other controls in it including Forms

Comment: And you just Create & Show the WinForms? Didn't know it was possible.

Comment: yea if you a reference to System.Windows.Forms you can declare the forms the same you would if you were working in WinForms but a lot of the properties are set to nothing including Parent and Owner

Comment: So how do you set the the MainWindow as Parent?

Comment: That would be in turn part of the question.  I was assuming that it somehow was on the WinForm Form object but it is not or at least not in the usual spots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to guess a little but I think your WinForms forms aren't actually children of the WPF MainWindow. I don't see how they could be.

So they're probably just other non-main Windows in your application, not proper children.

That means you have 2 collections to look at:

- WinForms : `System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms`
- WPF : `System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows`

Or maybe `MainWindow.OwnedWindows` for the WPF side.

Comment: Thank you these were the collections that i was looking for